# Rails 2.3.x, is there any ruby gems for editing yml locale files?

Tags: rubygems, locale, ruby-on-rails-2, i18n-gem

I need to know if is there any ruby gems for editing yml locale files with a web interface? I remember I have seen a kind of, but I forget the name.

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is this one: https://github.com/Locale/localeapp homepage here: http://www.localeapp.com/

There is also a textmate plugin, but now i don't remember what its called :p